# I can't build C# code with Monodevelop on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop on Raspberry Pi and copied one unit of project folder for C# which I had already written with VisualStudio2017 on Windows PC to Raspberry Pi. But, I can’t built(compiled) the source code with MonoDevelop.

What should I do?

Raspberry pi: CM3+(32GB) and CMIO
Raspbian:10(buster)

I installed MonoDevelop on Raspberry Pi and copied one unit of project folder for C# which I had already written with VisualStudio2017 on Windows PC to Raspberry Pi. But, I can’t built(compiled) the source code with MonoDevelop.

What should I do?

By the way, the following error message is output in MonoDevelop when building.

> [331
>   Imported project
>   “/Home/pi/,cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/1068_1/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets”
>   Was not found.
>   Check whether the  declaration path is correct, and whether the file exists on the disk. (MSB4019) '' ]

(the original message is Japanese.)

When I used `cd` and `ls` with CUI, I could not find `Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets` in the folder `1608_1` (there were many files with similar names).

By the way, executable file that I have already built on Windows PC works on Raspberry Pi.

I would like to make a program roughly with VisualStudio on Windows PC and adjust fine debugging with MonoDevelop on the target machine, Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [different version of Mono.](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/14875#issuecomment-500072289)

Hope this helps!